# Delay/load issue in the first transition in this BS multi slide

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Any idea why I am getting a white space/gap on the first slide of my transition?

```js
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
  const minPerSlide = 4
  let next = el.nextElementSibling
  for (var i = 1; i < minPerSlide; i++) {
    if (!next) {
      // wrap carousel by using first child
      next = items[0]
    }
    let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
    el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
    next = next.nextElementSibling
  }
})
```

```css
.container,
#recipeCarousel {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.custom-carousel-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
}

.subtitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card-img::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}


/* medium and up screens */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.8/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid text-center my-3 position-relative">
  <h1 class="custom-carousel-title">Title</h1>
  <h5 class="subtitle">Sub-title</h5>
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
    <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682687982470-8f1b0e79151a?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1701657130280-19757c5c7f31?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682685796852-aa311b46f50d?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695794947-17061dc284dd?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682695796497-31a44224d6d6?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1682688759157-57988e10ffa8?q=80&w=2070&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h5 class="mt-2 fw-light">advances one slide at a time</h5>
</div>
```

Here is a Codepen, if needed, for testing [Pen](https://codepen.io/wpembraced/pen/gOqVLYw)

There is this weird transition on the first slide causing a gap on the left of the first slide while transitioning.  The second and third slides are sliding just fine.

Comment: Took the code from your pen and put it here. Questions should include a full minimal example (if possible), not just a link to a codepen, which may be deleted in the future, making this question irrelevant.